# Will this schematic work?

Tags: battery-charging

I'm using the [TP4056](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) to charge a LiPo cell in my project. I want to use the ICs pins 6 and 7 and connect them to the ATMEL Atmega328p digital pins 11 and 12 (pins D7 and D8 on Arduino board) and use these pin to sense when the device is charging and when the battery is full. The input to VCC is 5V and the LEDs used in the circuit have a Vf 2.0V.

[image: Charge Circuit]

Comment: Nice question, well written, but where I don't know what are pins 11 and 12 on an Arduino board.

Comment: They are digital input pins. Pins D7 and D8

Comment: You're more likely to get a good answer on EE for this kind of thing (it's not really related to Arduino but to the TP4056). I'll migrate it over there for you.

Comment: Some decoupling on the DC input side might be a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need a 10uF bypass capacitor on the power input (ideally a low ESR cap), it should be as close to pin 4 as possible with a thick trace.

TEMP also needs to set using a divider.  If this pin is above 0.8 * VCC or below 0.45 * VCC for more than 0.15 seconds, charging stops.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7IUXd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

PCB Layout will be critical for heat dissipation.  With a deeply discharged battery bulk charging starts at a battery voltage of 3V.  At 5V input, you are going to be dissipating 2W ([5V-3V] * 1A) as heat in the SO8 package which is a lot for that package.  You might want to consider starting with a lower charge current when you begin testing and work your way up to 1A watching the temperature of the IC.  You could use a 5K or 10K potentiometer for R12 in a prototype to facilitate this.

Usually the datasheet would provide die to package thermal resistance and package to board thermal resistance for a couple of example layouts, but the only datasheet I could find for this part does not provide any of this information.

If you are designing a product for production you might look at a switching converter instead, TI and others make parts with decent datasheets, application notes and reference designs that will ease the process.  A well designed switching converter can be 90-95% efficient or more resulting in almost no waste heat at all.

Comment: Looks like the pad should be connected to ground too.  The datasheet appears to be poorly translated, but it looks like you can either ground it or leave it floating.  Grounding the pad and using a bunch of thermal vias to a continuous ground plane on the board bottom will help with the heat dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Dean's answer.

I would not tie the TEMP line directly to ground. You may not need it right now but who knows what will happen down the road.

I'd chose one of two options.

1. As Dean suggests, pin the TEMP line to 50-60% rail voltage and bring the signal out to the battery. If you don't hook it up, it will just trick it into thinking the temperature is in range. If you do hook it up, it should over-ride the resistor values. However I'd up Dean's resistor values by a factor of 10
2. Bring the TEMP line out to the connector as is and add a jumper that pulls it to ground if you do not want to use it.

**ALSO**

I would also tie the CE to Vcc through a pull-up, not hard wired, and bring it out to the Arduino connector. If you have the control pins available, you may want to consider driving the CE pin directly from the micro. You may not need it right now, but at least it gives you the capability later if things change.

This might be especially important if the battery is intended to be integral to your assembly. It is better to allow the battery to discharge a bit rather than continually charge it when on line power. Of course, for that you would need to know hen line power is available and monitor the battery voltage and enable the charger when need be.

**ALSO 2**

You really ought to have some form of protection on the input there. Specifically reverse connection and over-voltage protection. You have not said where you are sourcing that Vcc from, but if it is a wall-wart, this is quite important since they come in a lot of shapes and sizes with different voltages on the same plug. It will be less critical if it is from a USB connector, though making sure it is wired right internally is still an issue. I always use three pin headers for this connection (J5) with the centre pin the ground so reversal does not matter.